# Why intellij not importing gradle AWS SDK libraries

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, gradle, azkaban

Working on gradle project very first time. (Open source - Azkaban framework).

I tried to add AWS SDK java as dependency in my project. But when I add it shows empty jar or sometime no jar is there.

Added dependency in build.gradle file.

```
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.X.Y')
```

When I added version "1.10.16", there is all source code in jar, but for higher version than "1.10.16", there is no source code except META-INF folder.

Can you please help me why it is showing strange behaviour ? 
or I forgot some project settings.

**Update : 1**

Here is my build.gradle file -

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.linkedin:gradle-dustjs-plugin:1.0.0'
    classpath 'de.obqo.gradle:gradle-lesscss-plugin:1.0-1.3.3'
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.4.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'distribution'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.10.47'
    }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }
}

/**
 * Helper that calls a command and returns the output.
 */
def cmdCaller = { commandln ->
  def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  exec {
    commandLine commandln
    standardOutput = stdout
  }
  return stdout.toString().trim()
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  apply plugin: 'idea'

  /**
   * Gets the version name from the latest Git tag
   */
  task createVersionFile() << {
    String gitCommitHash = cmdCaller(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD']);
    String gitRepo = cmdCaller(['git', 'config', '--get', 'remote.origin.url']);
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm zzz')

    String versionStr = version + '\n' +
        gitCommitHash + '\n' +
        gitRepo + '\n' +
        formattedDate + '\n'

    File versionFile = file('build/package/azkaban.version')
    versionFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    versionFile.write(versionStr)
  }

  /*
   * Print test execution summary when informational logging is enabled.
   */
  test {
    testLogging {
      afterSuite { desc, result ->
        if (desc.getParent()) {
          logger.info desc.getName()
        } else {
          logger.info "Overall"
        }
        logger.info "  ${result.resultType} (" +
              "${result.testCount} tests, " +
              "${result.successfulTestCount} passed, " +
              "${result.failedTestCount} failed, " +
              "${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
      }
    }
  }
}

project(':azkaban-common') {
  configurations {
    all {
      transitive = false
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    compile('com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1')
    compile('com.h2database:h2:1.3.170')
    compile('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9')
    compile('commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1')
    compile('commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.8')
    compile('commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4')
    compile('commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:1.5')
    compile('commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.1')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
    compile('commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6')
    compile('commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1')
    compile('commons-pool:commons-pool:1.6')
    compile('javax.mail:mail:1.4.5')
    compile('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.0')
    compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.16')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.28')
    compile('net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.3')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.2')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:2.1.1')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1')
    compile('org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7')
    compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.5')
    compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.5')
    compile('org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.26')
    compile('org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:6.1.26')
    compile('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1')
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core'

    testCompile('junit:junit:4.11')
    testCompile('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3')
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
  }

}

project(':azkaban-migration') {
  configurations {
    all {
      transitive = false
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    compile(project(':azkaban-common'))
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
    compile('commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4')
    compile('commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:1.5')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.0')
    compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.16')
  }

  task copyLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from('build/libs')
    into('build/package/lib')
  }

  task copyDeps(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from(project(':azkaban-common').configurations.compile)
    from(configurations.compile)
    into('build/package/lib')
  }

  task copyPackage(type: Copy) {
    from('src/package')
    into('build/package')
  }

  task copy(dependsOn: [
      'createVersionFile',
      'copyLibs',
      'copyDeps',
      'copyPackage']) {
  }
}

project(':azkaban-webserver') {
  apply plugin: 'lesscss'
  apply plugin: 'dustjs'

  ext.pegasusVersion = '1.15.7'

  configurations {
    all {
      transitive = false
    }
    generateRestli {
      transitive = true
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    compile(project(':azkaban-common'))
    compile('com.linkedin.parseq:parseq:1.3.7')
    compile('com.linkedin.pegasus:data:' + pegasusVersion)
    compile('com.linkedin.pegasus:gradle-plugins:' + pegasusVersion)
    compile('com.linkedin.pegasus:li-jersey-uri:' + pegasusVersion)
    compile('com.linkedin.pegasus:pegasus-common:' + pegasusVersion)
    compile('com.linkedin.pegasus:restli-common:' + pegasusVersion)
    compile('com.linkedin.pegasus:restli-server:' + pegasusVersion)
    compile('com.linkedin.pegasus:r2:' + pegasusVersion)
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.2')
    compile('commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
    compile('commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.1')
    compile('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.0')
    compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.16')
    compile('net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.3')
    compile('org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7')
    compile('org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:2.0')
    compile('org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.26')
    compile('org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:6.1.26')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.5')

    generateRestli('com.linkedin.pegasus:generator:' + pegasusVersion)
    generateRestli('com.linkedin.pegasus:restli-tools:' + pegasusVersion)
  }

  sourceSets {
    main {
      java {
        srcDirs 'src/main/java', 'src/restli/generatedJava', 'src/restli/java'
      }
    }
  }

  task restliTemplateGenerator(type: JavaExec) {
    mkdir 'src/restli/generatedJava'

    main = 'com.linkedin.pegasus.generator.PegasusDataTemplateGenerator'
    args = ['src/restli/generatedJava','src/restli/schemas']
    classpath = configurations.generateRestli
  }

  task restliRestSpecGenerator(dependsOn: [restliTemplateGenerator], type: JavaExec) << {
    mkdir 'src/restli/generatedRestSpec'

    main = 'com.linkedin.restli.tools.idlgen.RestLiResourceModelExporterCmdLineApp'
    args = ['-outdir', 'src/restli/generatedRestSpec', '-sourcepath', 'src/restli/java']
    classpath = configurations.generateRestli
  }

  task restli(dependsOn: restliTemplateGenerator) << {
  }

  compileJava.dependsOn.add('restli')

  lesscss {
    source = fileTree('src/main/less') {
      include 'azkaban.less'
      include 'azkaban-graph.less'
    }
    dest = 'build/less'
  }

  dustjs {
    source = fileTree('src/main/tl')
    dest = 'build/dust'
  }

  task createDirs() << {
    file('build/package/extlib').mkdirs()
    file('build/package/plugins').mkdirs()
  }

  task copyWeb(type: Copy) {
    from('src/web')
    into('build/package/web')
  }

  task copyLess(type: Copy, dependsOn: ['lesscss', 'copyWeb']) {
    from('build/less')
    into('build/package/web/css')
  }

  task copyDust(type: Copy, dependsOn: ['dustjs', 'copyWeb']) {
    from('build/dust')
    into('build/package/web/js')
  }

  task copyDeps(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from(project(':azkaban-common').configurations.compile)
    from(configurations.compile)
    into('build/package/lib')
  }

  task copyLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from('build/libs')
    into('build/package/lib')
  }

  task copyPackage(type: Copy) {
    from('src/package')
    into('build/package')
  }

  task copy(dependsOn: [
      'createVersionFile',
      'createDirs',
      'copyLess',
      'copyDust',
      'copyDeps',
      'copyLibs',
      'copyPackage']) {
  }
}

project(':azkaban-execserver') {
  configurations {
    all {
      transitive = false
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    compile(project(':azkaban-common'))
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
    compile('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.0')
    compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.16')
    compile('org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.26')
    compile('org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:6.1.26')
    compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.5')
    compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.5')

    testCompile('junit:junit:4.11')
    testCompile('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3')
    testCompile(project(':azkaban-common').sourceSets.test.output)
  }

  task createDirs() << {
    file('build/package/extlib').mkdirs()
    file('build/package/plugins').mkdirs()
  }

  task copyDeps(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from(project(':azkaban-common').configurations.compile)
    from(configurations.compile)
    into('build/package/lib')
  }

  task copyLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from('build/libs')
    into('build/package/lib')
  }

  task copyPackage(type: Copy) {
    from('src/package')
    into('build/package')
  }

  task copy(dependsOn: [
      'createVersionFile',
      'createDirs',
      'copyDeps',
      'copyLibs',
      'copyPackage']) {
  }
}

project(':azkaban-soloserver') {
  dependencies {
    compile(project(':azkaban-common'))
    compile(project(':azkaban-webserver'))
    compile(project(':azkaban-execserver'))
  }

  task createDirs() << {
    file('build/package/extlib').mkdirs()
    file('build/package/plugins').mkdirs()
  }

  task copyDeps(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from(configurations.compile)
    into('build/package/lib')
  }

  task copyLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from('build/libs')
    into('build/package/lib')
  }

  task copyPackage(type: Copy) {
    from('src/package')
    into('build/package')
  }

  task copyWeb(type: Copy, dependsOn: ':azkaban-webserver:copy') {
    from(project(':azkaban-webserver').files('build/package/web'))
    into('build/package/web')
  }

  task copySql(type: Copy) {
    from(project(':azkaban-sql').files('src/sql'))
    into('build/package/sql')
  }

  task copy(dependsOn: [
      'createVersionFile',
      'createDirs',
      'copyDeps',
      'copyLibs',
      'copyPackage',
      'copyWeb',
      'copySql']) {
  }
}

project(':azkaban-sql') {
  task concat() << {
    ext.destFile = 'build/sql/create-all-sql-' + version + '.sql';
    ant.concat(destfile: destFile, fixlastline: 'yes') {
      logger.info('Concating create scripts to ' + destFile)
      fileset(dir: 'src/sql') {
        exclude(name: 'update.*.sql')
        exclude(name: 'database.properties')
      }
    }
  }
}

project(':azkaban-test') {
  apply plugin: 'distribution'

  distributions {
    animal {
      baseName = 'test-animal'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/animal' }
      }
    }

    embedded {
      baseName = 'test-embedded'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/embedded' }
      }
    }

    embedded2 {
      baseName = 'test-embedded2'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/embedded2' }
      }
    }

    embedded3 {
      baseName = 'test-embedded3'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/embedded3' }
      }
    }

    embeddedBad {
      baseName = 'test-embedded-bad'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/embeddedBad' }
      }
    }

    execpropstest {
      baseName = 'test-execpropstest'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/execpropstest' }
      }
    }

    exectest1 {
      baseName = 'test-exectest1'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/exectest1' }
      }
    }

    exectest2 {
      baseName = 'test-exectest2'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/exectest2' }
      }
    }

    logtest {
      baseName = 'test-logtest'
      contents {
        from { 'src/test/resources/executions/logtest' }
      }
    }
  }

  distZip.dependsOn build, animalDistZip, embeddedDistZip, embedded2DistZip,
      embedded3DistZip, embeddedBadDistZip, execpropstestDistZip,
      exectest1DistZip, exectest2DistZip, logtestDistZip

  distTar.dependsOn build, animalDistTar, embeddedDistTar, embedded2DistTar,
      embedded3DistTar, embeddedBadDistTar, execpropstestDistTar,
      exectest1DistTar, exectest2DistTar, logtestDistTar
}

distributions {
  migration {
    baseName = 'azkaban-migration'
    contents {
      from { project(':azkaban-migration').file('build/package') }
    }
  }

  webserver {
    baseName = 'azkaban-web-server'
    contents {
      from { project(':azkaban-webserver').file('build/package') }
    }
  }

  execserver {
    baseName = 'azkaban-exec-server'
    contents {
      from { project(':azkaban-execserver').file('build/package') }
    }
  }

  soloserver {
    baseName = 'azkaban-solo-server'
    contents {
      from { project(':azkaban-soloserver').files('build/package') }
    }
  }

  sql {
    baseName = 'azkaban-sql'
    contents {
      from { project(':azkaban-sql').file('src/sql') }
      from { project(':azkaban-sql').file('build/sql') }
    }
  }
}

// Set up dependencies for distribution tasks.
//
// N.B. The extension for the Tar tasks is set since the Gradle Distribution
//      plugin uses the .tar file extension for GZipped Tar files by default.
//
// N.B. When the distribution tasks are run, azkaban-execserver,
//      azkaban-webserver, azkaban-migration, and azkaban-soloserver only
//      have a dependency on the azkaban-common build artifacts. As a result,
//      the full :azkaban-common:build task is not run, meaning that the
//      tests are skipped. Thus, the dependency on :azkaban-common:build
//      is set here so that the azkaban-common unit tests are run when running
//      the dist tasks.

migrationDistTar.dependsOn ':azkaban-common:build', ':azkaban-migration:copy'
migrationDistTar.compression = Compression.GZIP
migrationDistTar.extension = 'tar.gz'
migrationDistZip.dependsOn ':azkaban-common:build', ':azkaban-migration:copy'

webserverDistTar.dependsOn ':azkaban-common:build', ':azkaban-webserver:copy'
webserverDistTar.compression = Compression.GZIP
webserverDistTar.extension = 'tar.gz'
webserverDistZip.dependsOn ':azkaban-common:build', ':azkaban-webserver:copy'

execserverDistTar.dependsOn ':azkaban-common:build', ':azkaban-execserver:copy'
execserverDistTar.compression = Compression.GZIP
execserverDistTar.extension = 'tar.gz'
execserverDistZip.dependsOn ':azkaban-common:build', ':azkaban-execserver:copy'

soloserverDistTar.dependsOn ':azkaban-common:build', ':azkaban-soloserver:copy'
soloserverDistTar.compression = Compression.GZIP
soloserverDistTar.extension = 'tar.gz'
soloserverDistZip.dependsOn ':azkaban-common:build', ':azkaban-soloserver:copy'

sqlDistTar.dependsOn ':azkaban-sql:concat'
sqlDistTar.compression = Compression.GZIP
sqlDistTar.extension = 'tar.gz'
sqlDistZip.dependsOn ':azkaban-sql:concat'

distTar.dependsOn migrationDistTar, webserverDistTar, execserverDistTar, soloserverDistTar, sqlDistTar
distZip.dependsOn migrationDistZip, webserverDistZip, execserverDistZip, soloserverDistZip, sqlDistZip

/**
 * Gradle wrapper task.
 */
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '1.12'
}
```

I followed all the 3 steps mentioned in link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/sdk-using-gradle.html

please check.

Comment: did you added repositories in your config?

Comment: @NitinDhomse Config means build.gradle. I worked on maven / ANT previously. I think build.gradle is very similar to pom.xml.

Comment: The behavior is normal: the jar is indeed empty. My guess is that you shouldn't use this dependency, but instead pick from the myriad of sub-projects listed here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws

Comment: @JBNizet I added depency using this link - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk

Also added snippet in question to explain how I added dependecy.

Comment: I understand that. But the jar of this project is empty. It's just a dummy project serving as a parent for all the subproject I linked to. You should add the subprojects you want to add as your dependencies. Not this dummy parent project.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, I got your point. I am working on this. Within 15 minutes, I will inform you about the result.

Also, following blog - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/sdk-using-gradle.html

Comment: @JBNizet Above updated solution worked for me. Now it is coming with source code. You can add answer, so that it will be helpful for others.